# Why use robot.txt on javascript files?

Tags: robots.txt

Is there any reason you should or shouldn't allow access to javascript or css files? Specifically common files such as jquery.

Comment: Why would one do that? I don’t know any search engine that is interested in JavaScript files.

Comment: Perhaps to use them as a type of CDN?

Comment: So you want to prevent others to use the jQuery files that are hosted on your website? I think there’s no need to add them to your `robots.txt`. If you do, e.g. Google won’t run the Ajax on your website and it will probably miss some content that is loaded per Ajax.

Comment: No it would be to allow them to use them. That's what I was wondering, right now they are blocked in my robots.txt and it caused Google's instant preview to not load embedded youtube videos correctly.

Comment: I can’t think of any reason, why you shouldn’t allow search engines to crawl them.

Comment: I thought it might be a security issue, I'm using a robots.txt that was recommended to me for use on wordpress sites.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14154/discussion-between-pvorb-and-raymond)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's widely accepted that search engines allocate a certain amount of bandwidth or # of URLs to a given site per day. So some webmasters like to block JS, CSS, and boilerplate images from the search engines to conserve their bandwidth so Google or Bing will crawl more pages instead of unnecessary images.

Googler, Matt Cutts, has asked in the past that webmasters don't do this (http://www.seroundtable.com/googlebot-javascript-css-14930.html).

It appears that Google would like to know exactly how your site behaves, with and without javascript. There's plenty of evidence that they're rendering out the entire page, as well as,  executing other javascript that is executed onPageLoad (e.g. Facebook comments).

If you block even common jQuery files, Google really doesn't know if it's a common jQuery implementation or if you've modified the core files, hence modifying the experience.

My suggestion would be to make sure all your JS, CSS, and boilerplate images are served off a separate domain or CNAME. I would monitor Googlebot's crawl through logs and [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en), and observe whether or not they're spending a lot of time and bandwidth to crawl these assets. If not, then just let them keep crawling it.

As each site behaves differently, you could experiment and block some of the more heavily requested files that are sucking down a large amount of bandwidth ... and then observe to see if Google's "pages crawled" increases.

Comment: isnt the `robots.txt` file simply for controlling whats ***indexed?*** to my undertanding, if i `disallow: /*.js$`, that doesnt mean the crawlers wont be able to load and execute JS files, it simply means dont index them??

Comment: @BugWhisperer Robots.txt controls what's crawled. If you disallow it means Google won't crawl the URL, however, it can still place that URL into its index. It may not know what is on the page since it didn't crawl it, but if Google find "enough" links to a URL, it may decide to include it and use the anchor text of the links as context of what to rank for it and how to describe that URL.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. if i `disallow: /*.css$` when google is crawling `index.php`, `index.php` would still be styled by `index.css`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily you should not (or have no need to) disallow access to JavaScript and CSS files in robots.txt.

However, search engines (specifically Google) are getting increasingly better at indexing JavaScript generated content. In most cases this is a good thing. On the other hand JavaScript has also been used to specifically hide content from the search engines, since it was believed that search engines did not execute JavaScript. This might not be the case anymore. However, it has been suggested that by disallowing these specific JavaScript files that generate the content in robots.txt then you also block the search engines from generating and seeing the hidden content - if that is the requirement.

This technique was suggested by seomofo in June 2010 with regards to [blocking affiliate marketing links](http://www.seomofo.com/marketing/seo-for-affiliate-links.html).